# Update a component list after deleting record

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component. It displays a list of records. You can click the delete icon, and as soon as you go to a different page and return to the list, the record is no longer there. How do I remove the record from the list without going to a different page?

I've tried using `componentWillUpdate()` and `componentDidUpdate()` and placing my `getTerritoryGeographies(this.props.params.id)` in those functions, but those functions keep calling the data and do not stop. I'm restricted to API limits.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import { getTerritoryGeographies, deleteTerritoryGeography } from '../actions/index';

import TerritoryTabs from './territory-tabs';

class TerritoryGeographyList extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    //console.log('this is the child props (TerritoryGeographyList)');
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getTerritoryGeographies(this.props.params.id);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
    this.props.getTerritoryGeographies(this.props.params.id);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
  }

  onDeleteClick(id) {
    this.props.deleteTerritoryGeography(id);

  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }

  renderTerritoryGeographyList() {
      return this.props.territoryGeographies.map((geography) => {
        return (
          <tr key={geography.Id}>
              <th scope="row" data-label="Country">
                <div className="slds-truncate">{geography.tpslead__Country__c}</div>
              </th>
              <td data-label="State/Provice">
                <div className="slds-truncate">{geography.tpslead__State__c}</div>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Postal Start">
                <div className="slds-truncate">{geography.tpslead__Zip_Start__c}</div>
              </td>
              <td data-label="Postal End">
                <div className="slds-truncate">{geography.tpslead__Zip_End__c}</div>
              </td>
              <td className="slds-text-align--right" data-label="Action">
                <button className="slds-button slds-button--icon" title="edit">
                      <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xlinkHref={editIcon}></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span className="slds-assistive-text">Edit</span>
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(geography.Id)} className="slds-button slds-button--icon" title="delete" data-aljs="modal" data-aljs-show="PromptConfirmDelete">
                      <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xlinkHref={deleteIcon}></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span className="slds-assistive-text">Delete</span>
                    </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
        );
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <TerritoryTabs id={this.props.params.id} listTab="geography">
          <Link to={"territory/" + this.props.params.id + "/geography/new"} className="slds-button slds-button--brand">
            Add New Geography
          </Link>
          <table className="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-m-top--large">
              <thead>
                <tr className="slds-text-title--caps">
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div className="slds-truncate" title="Country">Country</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div className="slds-truncate" title="State/Provice">State/Provice</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div className="slds-truncate" title="Postal Start">Postal Start</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div className="slds-truncate" title="Postal End">Postal End</div>
                  </th>
                  <th className="slds-text-align--right" scope="col">
                    <div className="slds-truncate" title="Action">Action</div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
            {this.renderTerritoryGeographyList()}
              </tbody>
            </table>
    </TerritoryTabs>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  //console.log(state);
  return { territoryGeographies: state.territoryGeographies.all
        };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTerritoryGeographies, deleteTerritoryGeography })(TerritoryGeographyList);
```

UPDATE: I figured out how do remove it by updating my `onDeleteClick()`, but it seems unnecessarily heavy for a react app. Thoughts?

```
  onDeleteClick(id) {
    this.props.deleteTerritoryGeography(id);
    var geographyIndex = this.props.territoryGeographies.findIndex(x => x.Id==id)
    this.setState(state => {
                this.props.territoryGeographies.splice(geographyIndex, 1);
                return {territoryGeographies: this.props.territoryGeographies};
            });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your question's description is not compatible with question's title .

Comment: does deleteTerritoryGeography raise an action creator? or just go to the DB and erase the record?

Comment: yes it calls an action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please post your action and reducer so that we can see what you are doing on the Redux side.

If you are renderings a list from data that is in the Redux store, you can use React-Redux's `connect` Higher Order Function to wrap the component, thus enabling access to the store as component props. So that part looks correct.

When you are firing the action creator, you should be passing in the id of the data that you would like deleted, and in your reducer, something like this:

`case 'DELETE_TERRITORY':
  const territoryId = action.data;
  return state.filter(territory => territory.id !== territoryId);`

When the reducer returns the new, filtered array, your component should update with the list minus the territory you just deleted.

Comment: This was perfect.

Comment: Is there a function that is similar to filter that allows you to locate an object and replace it with another?

Comment: Thanks! Very cool +_+

Answer (score -1):

This code controls whether the deletion operation is performed correctly. Returns the state to the first state if the deletion operation fails

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    handleDelete = async productId => {

        const originalProducts = this.state.products;
        const products = this.state.products.filter(p => productId !== p.productId);
        this.setState({ products });

        try {
            const result = await deleteProduct(productId);
            if (result.status === 200) {
                // codes goes here. for example send notification
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404) {
                // codes goes here. for example send notification
            }

            this.setState({ products: originalProducts });
        }
    }
```

## reactjs